# Find only data points in the last 3 years from today

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataset with one of the columns as a `Date`. I need to subset the dataset based on all those dates that are in the last three years.

So if I run the script today, it needs to keep only those dates that are less than three years from today, if I had to run it tomorrow, it would return those dates that are less than three years from tomorrow.

My sample dataset is as below:

```
df <- structure(list(TransactionDate = structure(c(1391472000, 1335225600, 
1405641600, 1332460800, 1420156800, 1401321600, 1445299200, 1305158400, 
1305158400, 1367366400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), .Names = "TransactionDate", row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = "data.frame")


   TransactionDate
1       2014-02-04
2       2012-04-24
3       2014-07-18
4       2012-03-23
5       2015-01-02
6       2014-05-29
7       2015-10-20
8       2011-05-12
9       2011-05-12
10      2013-05-01
```

This is what I was trying.

```
newDF <- as.data.frame(df[which((as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), '%Y')) - (as.numeric(format(df$TransactionDate, '%Y')))) <= 3),])
```

This gives me:

```
  df[which((as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y")) - (as.numeric(format(df$TransactionDate, "%Y")))) <= 3), ]
1                                                                                                2014-02-04
2                                                                                                2014-07-18
3                                                                                                2015-01-02
4                                                                                                2014-05-29
5                                                                                                2015-10-20
```

The output that I am expecting is to exclude the first entry `2014-02-04` from the above output since it is more than three years from today, even though it is from `2014`. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What about `2012-04-24`

Comment: @akrun, when I mentioned first entry, I was meaning the first entry from the output from my code. Since `2012-04-24` is more than three years from today, I do want it to be excluded. I have modified the question to make this clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
newdf <- df %>%
  filter(TransactionDate >= Sys.Date() - years(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

With just base R:

```
R> recent <- subset(df, as.Date(TransactionDate) >= Sys.Date() - 1095)
R> head(recent)
  TransactionDate
3      2014-07-18
5      2015-01-02
6      2014-05-29
7      2015-10-20
```

Comment: As long as the code isn't for a legal/regulatory requirement where leap year extra day might matter